# Is this the right way to remove a folder on a separate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am exercising my multi-threading skills in java. Below is a piece of code that is supposed to remove a folder and make sure that:

```
if (freshDB) {
    LOG.warn("Refreshing the database!");
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    final Future<Boolean> result = executorService.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call() {
            return FileHandler.removeFolder(dbLocation);
        }
    });

    do {
        // makes sure the folder is removed
    }
    while (result.get() == false);
}
```

Is this the right way to do it? if not why? please elaborate.

Comment: It would fail if files inside the folder are already open. why do you want to create a separate thread for this?

Comment: You should run it and observe wether it does what you want. Then post specific questions if you run into an issue.

Comment: @Bhavik Shah well true, but in terms of multi-threading. is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: @Preception It does what I want, but as you know, multithreading issues are hard to see.

Comment: @Hossein : according to me NO. Its a sequencial process because it is synchronized at the OS level. having a multithread won't do much good

Comment: @Bhavik Shah The important thing here is that I need to make sure that the folder is removed, becuase the next lines (not included here) is dependent on this folder removal.

Comment: @Hossein : If that is the case then you should NOT use multithreading as the order of which thread will run first is undefined. It may happen the the folder is not deleted and the other code runs. however you can ad a check something like `isFolderExists()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not.

First of all, the loop at the end doesn't make much sense. `result.get()` will always return the same value: the submitted task is excuted only once, and `result.get()` will return the result of this single execution.

And anyway, what's the point of starting a new thread if the initial thread immediately stops, waiting for the started thread to be finished? Doing everything in the initial thread would be much simpler, and more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Makesure the following method is Synchronised

`FileHandler.removeFolder()`

[Synchronization in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html)